# Overlap an image over a bootstrap thumbnail

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Firstly I have tried to re create this within a JSfiddle but unable to, so apologies for that. I am using bootstrap within my site and using the thumbnail class to set out my images. What I am struggling with is placing another image over the top of the image within the thumbnail. Ive played around with the positions to the best of my knowledge but cannot get around this

The page is at

```
http://46.32.253.11/our_team
```

What you will notice is a pin on the left, I would like that to stick to the top of the pic, like sticking a picture to a wall.

Ideally I would like to know the rules for aligning such images so that I can learn from this, or if anyone doe shave an answer could they explain briefly what is happening, so again i can learn from this.

Any help is appreciated as I need to get this project completed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it by using following markup in your current markup. Write your `<img class="team" alt="" src="/assets/teresa.jpg">` outside of `<div class="pin"></div>` and make following changes in your CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="span4">

    <div class="thumbnail">

        <div class="pin"></div>
        <img class="team" alt="" src="/assets/teresa.jpg">         
        <h4 class="team">Teresa Beggs</h4>
        <p class="team" href="#myModal99" data-toggle="modal">Operations Director</p>

    </div>       

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.thumbnail {
    border: medium none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; /* Added Lower Z-Index Value */
}

.pin {
    background: url("/assets/purplepin.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 100px; /* Added Height of image */
    width: 100px; /* Added Width of image */
    left: 100px; /* Added Left Position */ 
    position: absolute; /* Added Position */
    top: -20px; /* Added Top Position */        
    z-index: 2; /* Added Higher Z-Index Value from thumbnail div */
}
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer, I can see how it works now, I guess the position of my html didnt help either. Just to expand on this , how would i get the pin to stay in the same position no matter the screen size ( responsive layout)

Comment: Kindly update this markup at http://46.32.253.11/our_team So I could analyze easily.

Comment: will get his done later tonight when im home and then let you know- thank you

Comment: its ok now, figured out how to adapt it to a responsive layout. Use precentages rather than pixels.. Thanks again Ahsan, big help today

Answer (score -1):

I checked the link mentioned in the question.

Found that for the image of Pin you are setting the background if a div having class name

".pin" using CSS. o the background image will never come on the image of the person.

Also change the CSS for ".pin" class. Add some width to this as the width of the person's

image.

I suggest you move

```
<img class="team" src="/assets/teresa.jpg" alt=""> out of the <div class="pin">
```

Then give me the HTML and I can then tell how to show the pin on the person's image.